# Xamarin forms ios fatal error in mono runtime - Native Crash Reporting

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

this project used to work on vs 2022. When I try to run my app in Release Mode in my IPhone in IOS 16.1 or in an Emulator of an IPAD in IOS 16.1 it crashed

```
    Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================
Got a abrt while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
```

I just want to Run My App in Release Mode just to make sure that the app is working but it crashed.

Here is the Info

```
xcrun simctl launch --stdout=/dev/ttys000 --stderr=/dev/ttys001 --terminate-running-process 901CD6DD-9670-4B2D-AC7A-B42CBDBD1EBA com.sistecsoft.oficlimovilconexionwnm
com.sistecsoft.oficlimovilconexionwnm: 17755
objc[17755]: Class NSURLSessionDelegate is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkServiceProxy.framework/NetworkServiceProxy (0x7ff8643501d0) and /Users/marcosbremont/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/901CD6DD-9670-4B2D-AC7A-B42CBDBD1EBA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/29B293D6-68A9-4B3F-BC83-6CEA50571B4B/OfiCliMovil.iOS.app/OfiCliMovil.iOS (0x109a96800). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
MonoTouch: Could not install sigaction override, unexpected sigaction implementation.
2022-12-01 11:37:12.492433-0400 OfiCliMovil.iOS[17755:437697] SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22 cs_flags=200, pid=17755
2022-12-01 11:37:12.492941-0400 OfiCliMovil.iOS[17755:437697] SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: OfiCliMovil.iOS[17755]/0#-1 LF=0
2022-12-01 11:37:12.514883-0400 OfiCliMovil.iOS[17755:437697] SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22 cs_flags=200, pid=17755
2022-12-01 11:37:12.515295-0400 OfiCliMovil.iOS[17755:437697] SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: OfiCliMovil.iOS[17755]/0#-1 LF=0

=================================================================
    Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================
Got a abrt while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

=================================================================
    Native stacktrace:
=================================================================
    0x1095b72a5 - /Users/marcosbremont/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/901CD6DD-9670-4B2D-AC7A-B42CBDBD1EBA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/29B293D6-68A9-4B3F-BC83-6CEA50571B4B/OfiCliMovil.iOS.app/OfiCliMovil.iOS : mono_dump_native_crash_info
    0x1095abd7e - /Users/marcosbremont/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/901CD6DD-9670-4B2D-AC7A-B42CBDBD1EBA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/29B293D6-68A9-4B3F-BC83-6CEA50571B4B/OfiCliMovil.iOS.app/OfiCliMovil.iOS : mono_h2022-12-01 11:37:12.688848-0400 OfiCliMovil.iOS[17755:438031] SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22 cs_flags=200, pid=17755
2022-12-01 11:37:12.689292-0400 OfiCliMovil.iOS[17755:438031] SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: OfiCliMovil.iOS[17755]/0#-1 LF=0
2022-12-01 11:37:12.930018-0400 OfiCliMovil.iOS[17755:437697] 
Unhandled Exception:
Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: No embeddedresource found for OfiCliMovil.App
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load (System.Object view, System.Type callingType) [0x00028] in <f73bbd03346342898c8d25da2f72eff8>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml[TXaml] (TXaml view, System.Type callingType) [0x00000] in <f73bbd03346342898c8d25da2f72eff8>:0 
  at OfiCliMovil.App.InitializeComponent () [0x00000] in <4725a47e2e564b1da49e93d1ce5f18b0>:0 
  at OfiCliMovil.App..ctor () [0x00011] in <4725a47e2e564b1da49e93d1ce5f18b0>:0 
  at OfiCliMovil.iOS.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching (UIKit.UIApplication app, Foundation.NSDictionary options) [0x00005] in <d28b8cb2535549bandle_native_crash
    0x1095b68df - /Users/marcosbremont/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/901CD6DD-9670-4B2D-AC7A-B42CBDBD1EBA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/29B293D6-68A9-4B3F-BC83-6CEA50571B4B/OfiCliMovil.iOS.app/OfiCliMovil.iOS : sigabrt_signal_handler
    0x7ff834c32c1d - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib : _sigtramp
    0x0 - Unknown
    0x7ff800132fe0 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib : abort
    0x1097aedd6 - /Users/marcosbremont/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/901CD6DD-9670-4B2D-AC7A-B42CBDBD1EBA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/29B293D6-68A9-4B3F-BC83-6CEA50571B4B/OfiCliMovil.iOS.app/OfiCliMovil.iOS : xamarin_unhandled_exception_handler
    0x1096659f5 - /Users/marcosbremont/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/901CD6DD-9670-4B2D-AC7A-B42CBDBD1EBA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/29B293D6-68A9-4B3F-BC83-6CEA50571B4B/OfiCliMovil.iOS.app/OfiCliMovil.iOS : mono_invoke_unhandled_exception_hook
    0x1095ab993 - /Users/marcosbremont/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/901CD6DD-9670-4B2D-AC7A-B42CBDBD1EBA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/29B293D6-68A9-4B3F-BC83-6CEA50571B4B/OfiCliMovil.iOS.app/OfiCliMovil.iOS : mono_handle_exception_internal
    0x1095a9eb9 - /Users/marcosbremont/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/901CD6DD-9670-4B2D-AC7A-B42CBDBD1EBA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/29B293D6-68A9-4B3F-BC83-6CEA50571B4B/OfiCliMovil.iOS.app/OfiCliMovil.iOS : mono_handle_exception
    0x10952c070 - /Users/marcosbremont/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/901CD6DD-9670-4B2D-AC7A-B42CBDBD1EBA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/29B293D6-68A9-4B3F-BC83-6CEA50571B4B/OfiCliMovil.iOS.app/OfiCliMovil.iOS : mono_amd64_throw_exception
    0x109f395b0 - Unknown
    0x1097aea5a - /Users/marcosbremont/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/901CD6DD-9670-4B2D-AC7A-B42CBDBD1EBA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/29B293D6-68A9-4B3F-BC83-6CEA50571B4B/OfiCliMovil.iOS.app/OfiCliMovil.iOS : xamarin_process_managed_exception
    0x1097b5dcd - /Users/marcosbremont/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/901CD6DD-9670-4B2D-AC7A-B42CBDBD1EBA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/29B293D6-68A9-4B3F-BC83-6CEA50571B4B/OfiCliMovil.iOS.app/OfiCliMovil.iOS : xamarin_invoke_trampoline
    0x1097b78d6 - /Users/marcosbremont/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/901CD6DD-9670-4B2D-AC7A-B42CBDBD1EBA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/29B293D6-68A9-4B3F-BC83-6CEA50571B4B/OfiCliMovil.iOS.app/OfiCliMovil.iOS : xamarin_arch_trampoline
    0x1097b83e6 - /Users/marcosbremont/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/901CD6DD-9670-4B2D-AC7A-B42CBDBD1EBA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/29B293D6-68A9-4B3F-BC83-6CEA50571B4B/OfiCliMovil.iOS.app/OfiCliMovil.iOS : xamarin_x86_64_common_trampoline
    0x11b3151bb - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:]
    0x11b31705f - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesWithActions:forCanvas:payload:fromOriginatingProcess:]
    0x11b31ce3b - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:]
    0x11a750098 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer completeApplicationLaunchWithFBSScene:transitionContext:]
    0x11adc236d - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask
    0x11a750b92 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke
    0x11a7505cf - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:]
    0x11a7509c8 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]
    0x11a750275 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:]
    0x11a75f0e1 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke
    0x11ac93363 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : +[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:fromCurrentState:actions:completion:]
    0x11ade042f - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContextAndCompletion
    0x11a75ed61 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]
    0x11a541f16 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.594
    0x11a54092c - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:]
    0x11a541ac3 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneO28a1a16a27e7f1606>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.xamarin_UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr,intptr&)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (System.Int32 argc, System.String[] argv, System.IntPtr principalClassName, System.IntPtr delegateClassName) [0x00000] in <153620f857f54f9c9ab1e7a1e6853772>:0 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.Type principalClass, System.Type delegateClass) [0x00041] in <153620f857f54f9c9ab1e7a1e6853772>:0 
  at OfiCliMovil.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <d28b8cb2535549b28a1a16a27e7f1606>:0
2022-12-01 11:37:12.937606-0400 OfiCliMovil.iOS[17755:437697] Unhandled managed exception: No embeddedresource found for OfiCliMovil.App (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException)
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load (System.Object view, System.Type callingType) [0x00028] in <f73bbd03346342898c8d25da2f72eff8>:0 
  at Xamarin.S.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]
    0x11b31b641 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:]
    0x11acc5c73 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:]
    0x7ff80547c41b - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iForms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml[TXaml] (TXaml view, System.Type callingType) [0x00000] in <f73bbd03346342898c8d25da2f72eff8>:0 
  at OfiCliMovil.App.InitializeComponent () [0x00000] in <4725a47e2e564b1da49e93d1ce5f18b0>:0 
  at OfiCliMovil.App..ctor () [0x00011] in <4725a47e2e564b1da49e93d1ce5f18b0>:0 
  at OfiCliMovil.iOS.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching (UIKit.UIApplication app, Foundation.NSDictionary options) [0x00005] in <d28b8cb2535549b28a1a16a27e7f1606>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.xamarin_UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr,intptr&)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (System.Int32 argc, System.String[] argv, System.IntPtr principalClassName, System.IntPtr delegateClassName) [0x00000] in <153620f857f54f9c9ab1e7a1e6853772>:0 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.Type principalClass, System.Type delegateClass) [0x00041] in <153620f857f54f9c9ab1e7a1e6853772>:0 
  at OfiCliMovil.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <d28b8cb2535549b28a1a16a27e7f1606>:0
OS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices : -[FBSScene _callOutQueue_agent_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:]
    0x7ff8054aa583 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices : __92-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createSceneWithIdentity:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.187
    0x7ff80548a46a - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices : -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:]
    0x7ff8054aa178 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices : __92-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createSceneWithIdentity:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke
    0x7ff80013ca3a - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib : _dispatch_client_callout
    0x7ff8001404bf - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib : _dispatch_block_invoke_direct
    0x7ff8054d0980 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices : __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__
    0x7ff8054d0876 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices : -[FBSSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible]
    0x7ff8054d09a8 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices : -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource]
    0x7ff800387035 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
    0x7ff800386f74 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : __CFRunLoopDoSource0
    0x7ff800386771 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : __CFRunLoopDoSources0
    0x7ff800380e73 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : __CFRunLoopRun
    0x7ff8003806f7 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : CFRunLoopRunSpecific
    0x7ff809c5c28a - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices : GSEventRunModal
    0x11b31962b - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIApplication _run]
    0x11b31e547 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : UIApplicationMain
    0x1097a4976 - /Users/marcosbremont/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/901CD6DD-9670-4B2D-AC7A-B42CBDBD1EBA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/29B293D6-68A9-4B3F-BC83-6CEA50571B4B/OfiCliMovil.iOS.app/OfiCliMovil.iOS : xamarin_UIApplicationMain
    0x124ff186b - Unknown
    0x124ff169b - Unknown

=================================================================
    Basic Fault Address Reporting
=================================================================
Memory around native instruction pointer (0x7ff834be630e):0x7ff834be62fe  ff ff c3 90 90 90 b8 48 01 00 02 49 89 ca 0f 05  .......H...I....
0x7ff834be630e  73 08 48 89 c7 e9 aa 9a ff ff c3 90 90 90 b8 53  s.H............S
0x7ff834be631e  00 00 02 49 89 ca 0f 05 73 08 48 89 c7 e9 92 9a  ...I....s.H.....
0x7ff834be632e  ff ff c3 90 90 90 b8 83 01 00 02 49 89 ca 0f 05  ...........I....

=================================================================
    Managed Stacktrace:
=================================================================
=================================================================
```

Comment: Do you have any embedded resource you are referencing in your XAML? `Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: No embeddedresource found for OfiCliMovil.App`

Comment: Did it work well in debug mode?